# Buildozer command failed while compiling kivy

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to package kivy for android but whenever I dot I get this error

```
Command failed: /Users/ulto4/miniforge3/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/Users/ulto4/Documents/vsc/myapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
```

I believe this has something to do with my NDK but I'm not sure.
I have java version 1.8.0, python3.8.9 and am on an M1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any kind of error message above the `Command failed` one that you can show us? It might help determining what's wrong